# Is it possible in Ubuntu app, start C++ function from javascript?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, javascript

I have application using QML and C++  and want to start C++ function from javascript . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

What you need to do is create a plugin.  This will allow you to import a C++ object (and only objects!) into your QML namespace.  Since you want a C++ function, you'll have to make a "dummy" object with a method that just calls the C++ function you desire.

To do this, you'll need to create two classes.  One will be a class for that dummy object mentioned above.  The second will inherit from `QQmlExtensionPlugin` and must call `qmlRegisterType` for the first class.

This has just been an overview -- for more details, see the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html).  I've also written up and example of a [QML plugin to read a file](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/14/reading-files-with-a-c%2B%2B-plugin-in-qml.html), which should be fairly close to what you'll need.